# How to compare object properties at the right level in Firebase?

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I may be missing something really simple here but I cant quite put my finger on it.

I have a `users = [];` that contains user objects pulled from Firebase.

[image]

As you can see it goes `users > id > property : value`

This is a different for `disliked_users` however, as it goes:

`users > id > property > id > property : value`

I am running this for loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < users.length; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < likesArray.length; j++){
      if((users[i].useruid == likesArray[j].likedUseruid)){
        console.log('match');
      }
      else {
        console.log('nothing');
      }
    }
  }
```

I try to match the users `useruid` i.e `users > id > useruid : CNzoqU9ZU(etc)`
to the `disliked_users dislikedUseruid`
However, I cannot work out how deep I need to go with the dislikesArray.

The dislikesArray is pulled from:

```
var dislikes = firebase.database().ref('users/' + 'CNzoqU9ZUsSMXBcvwYqe0VdWuwp2' + '/disliked_users');
```

When I run the code it always logs out `nothing` as it never finds a match.

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase Database console. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: Firstly where is likesArray from? also i think you need to add more code..because where you defined dislikes, you also have to still retrieve the data using a `.once()` then `.val()`